# Drupal 8: Inserting a block/view into the menu twig template

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

Is it possible to have a block/view render from within my Mega Menu twig template?

I've created a region, created a view/block and added that block to the region. But it's a matter of having that content from the view displayed in my menu.

I started off by considering I may be able to simply have a region specified from within my twig menu loop.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add something to your template, you need to use preprocess function in your module/theme. For example, you can add view variable using [`views_embed_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.module/function/views_embed_view/8.2.x) function:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  switch ($variables['menu_name']) {
    case 'mega-menu':
      $variables['my_view'] = views_embed_view('my_view');
      break;
  }
}
```

After this, `$my_view` variable will be defined in your `menu--mega-menu.html.twig` template.

Adding block is a bit more difficult. Please take a look at [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/153195) answer.

Comment: I've got: $variables['megamenu-marketsviews'] = views_embed_view('mega_menu_markets');  but on the front end it's simply displaying the number 0. In my view preview it shows 1 result (with the text etc) as expected.

Comment: Try to use underscore instead of dash in the name of your variable: `$variables['megamenu‌_marketsviews']`. Also make sure that your view has no arguments (or you pass all required arguments) and that you use correct display id.